# Reading in the dark, faster than light

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

Explain the following situations:

1. > Mr and Mrs Hill were both sitting up reading in their double-bed late one night. Finally Mrs Hill got up, turned out the light, and went to sleep. Even though it was now completely dark, Mr Hill kept on reading.
2. > John lived on the 14th floor of an apartment building. Whenever his mother visited, she had to be content to get off at the 8th floor and walk the rest of the way — even though the lift went right to the top.
3. > Last night Peter turned off the light in the bedroom and managed to get into bed before the room went dark, even though his bed was on the other side of the room.
4. > A lady found a fly floating in her vegetable soup. Embarrassed, the waiter apologised and returned the soup to the kitchen. He then simply removed the fly and brought back the same plate of soup. After one taste, the woman said, "This is the same soup."

Comment: These are _old_, and the answers well-known.

Comment: Also, you're asking several questions in one post, which could make this "too broad".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. > He was reading an e-book with an illuminated screen.
2. > She was too short to reach the highest buttons in the lift for the floors above the 8th.
3. > It was still light outside, so he could see perfectly well even with his light switched off.
4. > She'd added pepper or other seasoning to the soup before noticing the fly.

Comment: The first one isn't what I wanted, but it works.

Answer (score 5):

Alternative answer to #1:

> Mr Hill is blind, and reads braille by touch.

Comment: That was exactly what I had in mind! Kudos!

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Mr Hill is reading with an e-reader that is either backlit or uses an LCD screen.
>  2. John's mother can't raise her arm enough to push any of the higher buttons.
>  3. Peter went to bed before twilight ended.
>  4. The soup had cooled off.

Comment: The first and last ones aren't what I wanted, but they do work.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a different answer for #1:

> Mr. and Mrs. Hill were in two separate rooms in individual double beds.

Answer (score 0):

1.

> They were reading on their phone/tablet/laptop.

2.

> The lift could only be stopped before 9th floor or at topmost floor.

3.

> There was a lamp beside his bed too. So he switched off the lamp before going to bed too.

4.

> She added her pepper to the soup before the fly.